# Transfer data from local directory to Azure Data Lake store with flume without hadoop

Tags: hdfs, flume, azure-data-lake, azure-hdinsight, flume-ng

**   I'm trying to ingest data that is located on a directory of my vm linux
     to a directory From my azure data lake store  with flume I do not know what type of sink to use or even if it is possible knowing that for the source I use a spooldir**

************** My flume conf file *********

## a1 is my flume agent

```
a1.sources = r1
a1.sinks = k1
a1.channels = c1

# Describe/configure the source
a1.sources.r1.type = spooldir
a1.sources.r1.spoolDir = home/
a1.sources.r1.fileHeader = true

#describe the sink ( here is my problem  i don't know what type of sink to use i don't find any documentation about it)
a1.sinks.k1.type = 
a1.sinks.k1.endpoint = 


# Use a channel which buffers events in memory

a1.channels.c1.type = memory
a1.channels.c1.capacity = 1000
a1.channels.c1.transactionCapacity = 100

# Bind the source and sink to the channel
a1.sources.r1.channels = c1
a1.sinks.k1.channel = c1
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any code or config you can share?

Comment: i have try some other sinks or source ,  i have edit the question and i put my flume.conf file

Comment: Have you ever been able to solve this ?